# Get Customer Login into Magento1.9.x mobile app using REST api

Tags: magento-1.9, api, rest-api, oauth, android

I have a magento website and I am trying to make a android app for it. I have configured the oauth authentication to consume magento rest api and also tested it with postman. Till now everything is fine after that when I am trying to login from my app I have to go to a page to authenticate the customer email id and password. Here problem arises when a customer want to login he has to be redirected to one page for authentication.

For resolving this issue I tried one extension from magento connect which is also seems to be not working. Please suggest some solutions for how to achieve this?
[Check the Extension here](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/rest-api-oauth-direct-login-extension.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this article hope this will help you

http://www.ipragmatech.com/magento-mobile-app-rest-api/

Comment: Actually I have gone through it and as I am new to it I am not able to understand how I will authenticate the customer with out taking him to the authorise url in browser.

Comment: Would you mind posting the answer here as we don't know if the external resource will remain available in the future?